# Geckobrowser mfinkle example not working, throwing binary inflate exception in line 29?

Tags: android, html, webview, gecko

I am working on this example from last many days and didn't came across to any solution related to GeckoView not able to load, When ever you try to launch the geckobrowser sample app available on github it throws error as inflate exception in line 29, for   
This is what causing the error, its not able to fine GeckoView class but when I searched, Its available in project.

I needed to use GeckoView because I am working on loading html5 webpages which are not responding properly in normal android webview previous to kitkat 4.4.....on kitkat everything works fine as the chromium stuff enhanced and added on. So to make my app compatible to earlier version we tried on loading html5 pages to mozilla which seems to be working fine till an extent and then thought of using its Geckoview in our app. But the example itself seems to be not working. If anyone has tried it or have an idea, really the help will be appreciated. Thanks.